# Apache Tiles: How to split Template.xml tiles-definition

Tags: xml, spring, templates, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

We have a very large project.

and each developers is working on different part of the UI but require to modify the template.xml.

is there a way split the template.xml using include tag or somehow modular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you configure Tiles currently (and if your UI is structured), but since you tagged the question with Spring MVC you could simply list all tile definitions in Spring config:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
   <property name="definitions">
     <list>
       <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
       <value>/WEB-INF/defs/widgets.xml</value>
       <value>/WEB-INF/defs/administrator.xml</value>
       <value>/WEB-INF/defs/customer.xml</value>
       <value>/WEB-INF/defs/templates.xml</value>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

(Example copied from [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html))

Comment: quick question...can "general" use something from "adminstrator"? Usually we have a main.jsp

Comment: user4127, you should put the most generic definitions at the top of the list. All definitions from 'general.xml' will be available to 'widgets.xml', 'administrator.xml', 'customer.xml' and 'templates.xml', but not the other way around.